# User specific issue - All applications showing in finder as file type 'package', and will not launch

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-mini

I have a 2011 Mac Mini running High Sierra (10.13.6).  While installing security update 2019-005 last month, the mini stopped in the final stage of updating, with the Apple Logo and progress bar showing less than a minute remaining. I didn't appear to be hung or frozen, the mouse was still responsive, but the install status stopped progressing.  I let it sit overnight, and the update never progressed any further, so I ended up power cycling the mini.

After the mini restarted, the primary administrator account that I use is not able to launch any applications.  In finder, all the applications in the /Applications folder are showing as having a file kind 'package', and not 'application'.  Because all the apps are not recognized as applications, all the dock shortcuts are displayed as question marks.  Strangely, other accounts (both administrator and standard user) on the mini are fine, and are able to launch these same applications.

Things I've tried so far:
- Disable gatekeeper - no noticeable difference with issue
- Reset ACLs on home folder of problem user
- Restart in safe mode - no noticeable difference with issue

I'm running out of ideas for troubleshooting as was wondering if anyone had any recommendations.